# Angular Universal RxJs "Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function"

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-universal

I am getting the following error on the universal server console log (only with SSR not `ng serve`)

> ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function

Here is how my service is set up

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject, from } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class BcProductService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private configsService: ConfigsService,
        private injector: Injector
    ) {}

    getProductById(product_id) {
        const data = { product_id: product_id };
        return this.http.get<any>('/getProductById', { params: data }).catch(err => this.errHandler(err));
    }

    errHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.error || "unknown error");
    }

}
```

*** I am subscribing to `getProductById()` in another component.

All over the internet I see ppl are forgetting `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` but i have that and the error only happens during server-side rendering. Am I importing the wrong `Observable`?

#### Versions

rxjs                              **6.3.2**
Angular CLI: **6.2.4**
Node: **9.2.0**
OS: **darwin x64**
Angular: **6.1.7**
rxjs-compat: **^6.3.3**

Comment: Read the docs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: @jonrsharpe it seems like you might know what is wrong. I am reading the docs. any other notes you can add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of RxJS 6, you need to use throwError instead of throw.

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

errHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throwError(error.error || "unknown error");
}
```

**Package.json:**

```
"rxjs": "6.3.2",
"rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
```

Note: carot(^) symbol is not used. Delete package.lock.json file and do 'npm install'.

Comment: doing build now

Comment: now `ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throwError is not a function`

Comment: Seems like you are using npm package which contains Rxjs 6 & Rxjs 5

Comment: in package.json, use these specific rxjs versions. this will solve the problem.  "rxjs": "6.3.2",
"rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",

Comment: I tried `"rxjs": "^6.3.2", "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2"`, and `npm i` and still same err

Comment: you need to remove carot '^' and try. "rxjs": "6.3.2", "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2". delete package.lock file

Comment: that seems to be the problem. You should add vs numbers to ur answer